# Cross-referencing within text

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, revtex

Is there a way to reference a place in the text using `\hyperref`, instead of using `\nameref` to reference the section that portion of text belongs to?

Probably a WME will help in getting my point across:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside]{revtex4}

\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@ssect@ltx}{\@xsect}{\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#8}\@xsect}{}{}%    Patch \<section>*
\xpatchcmd{\@sect@ltx}{\@xsect}{\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#8}\@xsect}{}{}% Patch \<section>
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH,pdfpagemode=UseNone}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\maketitle

\section*{FirstSection--$E \times H$ vs.$\ \textbf{E} \times \textbf{H}$}
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text 
\bf I want to return here, not at the beginning of FirstSection \rm    \label{sec:marker1} \nameref{sec:marker2}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\section*{SecondSection} \label{sec:marker2}
You can also see in \nameref{sec:marker1} that \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you interested in obtaining the section title or just the section number? Also, add some more detail around the use of `revtex` and why previous questions answered in this respect didn't answer your question.

Comment: I believe the OP thought referencing for PDF shortcut, am I wrong?

Comment: Werener, previous questions did give an answer when you need to go back to the beginning of a section. But, suppose, you have a large amount of text that belongs to the section, say several pages long, and the point you're referencing is buried somewhere in the third page. You don't want to go back to the beginning of the section and go through all three pages to get back to that particular sentence. Hope I explained it clearly why I need that kind of cross-referencing.

Comment: @ganzewoort: You need to tell us why REVTeX is so important, and why you are refusing to use `revtex4-1`. I don't know about anyone else, but I'm inclined to ignore your questions until you begin using a maintained document class. As I've said before, there was about 10 years between 4 and 4.1, so this makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue a `\phantomsection` just before marking the `\label`. `\phantomsection` sets a PDF mark for subsequent `\label`s that the accompanying `\ref` will jump to (forward or backward). See section **4 Additional user macros** of the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-130004).

Here is your minimal example showing the location:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside]{revtex4}

\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@ssect@ltx}{\@xsect}{\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#8}\@xsect}{}{}%    Patch \<section>*
\xpatchcmd{\@sect@ltx}{\@xsect}{\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#8}\@xsect}{}{}% Patch \<section>
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH,pdfpagemode=UseNone}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\maketitle

\section*{\texorpdfstring{FirstSection--$E \times H$ vs.$\ \textbf{E} \times \textbf{H}$}{FirstSection-E x H vs. E x H}}
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text 
\bf I want to return here, not at the beginning of FirstSection \rm \phantomsection   \label{sec:marker1} \nameref{sec:marker2}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\section*{SecondSection} \label{sec:marker2}
You can also see in \nameref{sec:marker1} that \ldots
\end{document}
```

In the above example, you'll notice the use of `\texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdf>}` which eliminates your `hyperref` warnings regarding bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks @Werner. Works great. I didn't even need to add \texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdf>}.

Comment: @ganzewoort: Thanks means nothing without an upvote! That's how SE works.

Comment: @ganzewoort: And you can (please) accept an answer by clicking at the check-mark located below the down-vote-arrow.

Comment: Sorry about that. Just checked it. Hope I did it right.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own block which you refer to. Take a look at this example and see if it works for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\placeref}[1]{%
    \newcounter{foo}%
    \refstepcounter{foo}\label{#1}}


\begin{document}
Some text here: this is where we \placeref{goplace} go.

\lipsum[30]

\newpage 
Take a look at page \ref{goplace} for details. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: this seems to be referencing the page, not the particular place in the text of that page which you want referenced.

Comment: Hnn. Maybe I didn't understand your requirement fully but if you want to reference the "place", what's wrong with simply using `\ref` with the section's label?

Comment: Sorry, @recluze, I take that back. This is exactly what I want. I checked it in my text. How do you replace the '1' as a reference, with text?

Comment: Never mind. Just saw your explanation on the question in the comment and I know what you mean. My answer wouldn't be valid (unless you use it in conjunction with the section label like, "See Section X (page Y) for details").

Comment: Hehe. Not sure about that though. Maybe you can use `nameref` somehow. Try posting a follow up question or update to this question to see if someone else can improve it.