# How to use nameref to refer to a section without including the output of any commands in the title of that section?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, todonotes

### Background (simplified)

I'm using the [todonotes package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) to add todonotes to sections in my documents. I have created a macro to add the todonotes to sections such that they appear alongside the section's entry in the table of contents. I am also using the `nameref` macro from the [hyperref package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to refer to various sections of my document by name. Partly because of this, my macro also allows a label to be specified for the section. Here's a somewhat simplified version of the output my macro produces:

```
\section[{\todo{A todonote about the foo section}}{foo}]{foo}%
\label{sec:foo}
```

### The problem

The trouble with this is that when using the `\nameref` to refer to a section with a todonote contained in the title, as above, the todonote also gets attached to the reference.

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{foo}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A reference to the \nameref{sec:bar} section
\end{itemize}

\section[{\todo{A todonote about the bar section}}{bar}]{bar}
\label{sec:bar}
A section called bar

\section{baz}
A section called baz

\end{document}
```

Which produces (after three or four compiles/builds for good measure):

[image: A screenshot of the output from the MWE demonstrating the problem]

#### What's happening:

So the call to `\nameref{sec:bar}` is presumably producing a reference which includes `{\todo{A todonote about the bar section}}{bar}` and todonotes is (correctly but undesirably) producing a duplicate todonote because of this. To clarify, I would like the reference to the bar section to be produced as just `bar` without the duplicate todonote.

### Approach to finding a solution

Although this is my use case, I would prefer to know how to make `nameref` ignore any commands within the section title as I feel this would probably be more generally useful (and not just for me).

As a side note, an alternative solution to ignoring the commands could possibly be to define some `nameref`-specific reference text for the section somehow. However, this is less desirable as it would require a little maintenance to keep it relevant to the section name.

Comment: @lockstep: Just curious, what's the notes tag intended to be used for/mean? (Is it in reference to the todonotes package?)

Comment: In a sense, yes, but I chose the more general tag. Feel free to replace [tag:notes] with [tag:todonotes].

Comment: @lockstep: Ah ok, thanks. I think I shall change it as, although [tag:todonotes] shows the problem I'm having with `nameref`, it's not actually the cause. There may be a [tag:todonotes] related solution, but it's not really a [tag:notes](-caused) problem, if that makes sense.

Comment: @egreg: Although I'm not sure if this might be slightly against the consensus on accepting solutions (somewhat relevant - http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/535/11869) I strongly agree that Stephan deserves a lot of credit. If you're saying that this is cool then I shall leave it as it (now) is, otherwise I shall accept your answer so that it will be the first a new user/visitor sees.

Comment: @Staves: Although it may require more maintenance (as you say), those that are willing to manually add the name can avoid `\nameref` entirely and just use `\hyperref[sec:section]{Section Name}` as in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45100/191899).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simplified version of Stefan Lehmke's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@namedisablecommands{}
\newcommand{\addnamedisablecommand}[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\@namedisablecommands{\renewcommand#1{}}%
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\renewcommand#1{}}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{ 
  \patchcmd{\T@nameref}
  {\let\label\@gobble}
  {\let\label\@gobble\@namedisablecommands}
  {}{}
}
\makeatother

\addnamedisablecommand{\todo[2][]}
```

Notice the changed syntax; to keep Stefan's write

```
\newcommand{\addnamedisablecommand}[2]{%
  \g@addto@macro\@namedisablecommands{\renewcommand#1#2{}}%
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\renewcommand#1#2{}}%
}
```

instead.

After doing this, `\@namedisablecommands` will expand to

```
\renewcommand\todo[2][]{}
```

which will neutralize its expansion. The warning

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\todo' on input line 47.
```

is avoided by adding `\todo` (or other similar commands) in the disabled command list for `hyperref`.

Comment: That's really much simpler ;-)

Comment: @StephanLehmke Yours was a very good inspiration.

Comment: Just saw egreg's comment on the question, so leaving Stephan's answer as the accepted one. (@StephanLehmke)

Comment: Really neat solution! I'm very interested in finding out if the method you and @StephanLehmke propose can be extended to limiting the scope of commands other than `\T@nameref`. I currently have a bounty on an open question that concerns, in part, limiting the scope of a TeX macro that invokes some lua code; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48516/5001. Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I already saw your comment, but I doubt there is a connection. What we did here is a rather standard method for deactivating commands which have "moved" to a place they don't belong, because like in this case they are part of some section heading or such which gets saved by `nameref`. This is well-known for instance in the context of `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`. Unfortunately, I don't see a connection with your case (protect macro names and arguments from search/replace).

Comment: @egreg: In regards to the warning (`Token not allowed in a PDF string`), I tried adding `\addnamedisablecommand{\todo}` after `\addnamedisablecommand{\todo[2][]}`  This did prevent the warning but a `\nameref` to the label in the following `\section[{\todo[linecolor=blue]{A todonote about the bar section}}bar]{bar}\label{sec:bar}` came out as `[linecolor=blue]A todonote about the bar sectionbar`  I think I understand why this is happening, the second disable `\addnamedisablecommand{\todo}` appears to override the first, but can the warning be prevented without messing up the reference?

Comment: @Staves: As I said above, you need to define a command `\newcommand\totwo[2]{\todo[#1]{#2}}` and use that instead of `\todo` with optional argument. Then you can normally disable `\totwo[2]`.

Comment: @Staves: I recommend to accept egreg's answer. People finding this later will want to use the simpler solution.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Ah ok, I shall define an intermediary command as you suggest and I have now accepted egreg's answer - cheers for all your help `:)`

Answer (score 12):

Interestingly, `\nameref` seems to know there are some things which should be disabled (for instance, `\label`), but it doesn't offer an interface for adjusting it.

Hence, patching seems to be a solution. I repeat the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@namedisablecommands{}%
\newcount\@namedisablegenericmacro
\newcommand\addnamedisablecommand[2]
{%
  \global\advance\@namedisablegenericmacro\@ne
  \expandafter\newcommand
  \csname @namedisablegobble\number\@namedisablegenericmacro\endcsname
  #2{}%
  \global\expandafter\let
  \csname @namedisablegobble\number\@namedisablegenericmacro\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname @namedisablegobble\number\@namedisablegenericmacro\endcsname
  \edef\@namedisablecommands{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\@namedisablecommands}%
    \let\noexpand#1\expandafter\noexpand
    \csname @namedisablegobble\number\@namedisablegenericmacro\endcsname
  }%
}
\AtBeginDocument
{%
  \patchcmd{\T@nameref}
  {\let\label\@gobble}
  {\let\label\@gobble\@namedisablecommands}
  {}{}%
}
\addnamedisablecommand{\todo}{[2][]}
\expandafter\pdfstringdefDisableCommands\expandafter
{%
  \@namedisablecommands
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{foo}
\begin{itemize}
\item A reference to the \nameref{sec:bar} section
\end{itemize}

\section[{\todo{A todonote about the bar section}}{bar}]{bar}
\label{sec:bar}
A section called bar

\section{baz}
A section called baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `\nameref` has built-in functionality to keep it from operating on certain commands, such as `\label`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have accepted it as it does indeed solve the problem I am experiencing. Presumably this could also be expanded to ignore/`gobble` any number of commands?

Comment: @Staves: Exactly, you can iterate the patch as often as you wish.

Comment: Nice one `:)`  Could the `\let` and `\@gobble` surrounding `\todo` be moved into the `\addnamedisablecommand` macro (around the `#1`)? - This works for me with `\todo` it but I'm not sure if there might be ramifications with other commands and so on...

Comment: I thought about that, but the next step of abstraction is a lot more effort. The main complication is to handle commands with differing numbers of arguments.

Comment: Ah, understood - cheers again!

Comment: Ok, even more generic. Give the number of arguments (up to 9) as the second argument to `\addnamedisablecommand`. Tested only for 1 :-) Although this is getting a bit absurd for the purpose...

Comment: Crikey, all singing all dancing `:P` I was just about to ask how to deal with arguments and this is now very much in line with a generalised approach that I was asking about in the question `:D`  Well done sir!

Comment: At the risk of more absurdity, is there any way to deal with optional arguments? Currently changing the `\todo` call to be `\todo[linecolor=blue]{A todonote about the bar section}` results in the reference text being produced as `linecolor=blue]A todonote about the bar sectionbar`

Comment: Next edit: Now you can put into the second argument the argument definition used by `\newcommand`. In the example for a macro with two arguments, one of which is optional.

Comment: Sweet, that's brilliant! I owe you a beer(/beverage of choice) `^^`

Comment: @StephanLehmke I still get ``Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `\todo'``, but it's probably unavoidable.

Comment: @egreg: Do you get that error when compiling Stephan's example code as it is (i.e. without modification)?

Comment: @egreg: True, but that's a different matter altogether. It comes from `hyperref`'s `\pdfstringdef` which converts the sectiontitle to text for the bookmark. You'll notice some garbage there produced by the todo command. I've now added a `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` for good measure, but note it has to work in an expandable way, so it cannot cope with optional arguments; no chance here. @Staves, if you want to get rid of both, you must define a second pseudo-`\todo` command with two arguments and use that whenever you'd use `\todo` with optional argument.

Comment: Gotcha, cheers Stephan `:)`